# Code not returning response to command

Tags: python, response, speech, function

Quick question: I'm using the Speech Python Module for voice recognition. Here's the code I have so far,

```
import speech
import time


def callback(phrase, listener):
    if listener == "hello":
        print "Hello sir."
        listener.stoplistening()

listener = speech.listenforanything(callback)
while listener.islistening():
    time.sleep(.5)
```

But it never prints "Hello sir." I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong. I've looked online, but there's not much documentation. Can anyone help?

Ps: I'm using a Windows 8 laptop 64-bit and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import speech
import time


def callback(phrase, listener):
    # I have used phrase is here
    if phrase == "hello":
        print "Hello sir."
        listener.stoplistening()

listener = speech.listenforanything(callback)
while listener.islistening():
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Comment: `//` is not for comments in Python, you need `#`

Comment: it is hard to understand your answer, can you explain ?

Comment: your comment is, explanation sorry, it should be accepted t.